# Can I share data between 2 aspects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, inversion-of-control, unity-container, interceptor

I work on a SOA written in C# .NET 4.0, the service itself uses unity as its IoC container. We configure unity via xml configuration. 
We have a few methods that are intercepted and inject extra features.

My problem is, I need to share values in the first executed interception (aspect) with a second aspect that executes immediately afterwards. Is this possible through xml configuration

Comment: Showing some code of your interceptors might give a better view of what you are doing.

Comment: Figured it out. IMethodInvocation.InvocationContext

Comment: Care to share your own solution as an answer? Otherwise delete your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to share data between two or more aspects.

Have a look at `IMethodInvocation.InvocationContext`.

Basically you can add data into this object and it will be available in the following aspects that execute.

Comment: Seems like InvocationContext does not persist between InterceptionBehavior when exceptions are thrown?